Flood fill algorithm in Qt Pixap is way too slow
Introduction
I am trying to implement the flood fill algorithm manually in my Qt Computer Graphics Project. I have used simple BFS algorithm to implement flood fill.
Problem

The simple BFS version of flood fill is taking a long time.
Why am I not getting any significant advantage of parallelizing the for loop

My Approaches

Initially I was using recursive DFS, then I switched to iterative BFS.
Moved the plotPoint function outside, I stored all the points to be colored in a pre allocated QVector but that didn't help either.
I thought parallelizing the plotPoint function will help  but it didn't help either, although I am not really sure if I have used openmp correctly.

My flood fill routines are as follows:

void MainWindow::iterativeFloodFill(int x, int y, QVector<QPoint> &interior)
{
    std::queue<QPoint> q;
    q.push(QPoint(x, y));

    int xdir[] = {0, -1, 1, 0};
    int ydir[] = {-1, 0, 0, 1};

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        QPoint p = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (visited.contains(p) || pts.contains(p))
            continue;

        interior.push_back(QPoint(p.x(), p.y()));
        visited.insert(p);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            QPoint neighbor = QPoint(p.x() + xdir[i], p.y() + ydir[i]);
            if (!visited.contains(neighbor) && !pts.contains(neighbor))
            {
                q.push(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_floodfill_clicked()
{
    if (polygonPoints.size() == 0) return;
    QPoint seed = polygonPoints[0];
    QVector<QPoint> interior_points;
    interior_points.reserve(1011);
    polygonPoints.clear();
    iterativeFloodFill(seed.x(), seed.y(), interior_points);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i<interior_points.size(); i++)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        plotPoint(interior_points[i], QColor(10,20,30));
    }
}
void MainWindow::plotPoint(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b)
{

    pts[QPoint(x, y)] =  QColor(r,g,b) ;
    int gridOffset = (ui->gridOffset->value()==0)?1:ui->gridOffset->value();
    int width = ui->workArea->width();
    int height = ui->workArea->height();
    int centerX=width/2;
    int centerY=height/2;
    int calcX = centerX+ x*gridOffset + gridOffset/2;
    int calcY = centerY -  y*gridOffset - gridOffset/2;
    colorPoint(calcX, calcY, r,g,b, gridOffset);
}
void MainWindow::plotPoint(QPoint pt, QColor col)
{
    plotPoint(pt.x(), pt.y(), col.red(), col.green(), col.blue());
}
void MainWindow::colorPoint(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, int penwidth=1) {

    QPixmap canvas=ui->workArea->pixmap();
    QPainter painter(&canvas);
    QPen pen=QPen(QColor(r,g,b),penwidth);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawPoint(x, y);

    ui->workArea->setPixmap(canvas);
}

Brief explanation of what each function does

plotPoint This function accepts (x, y) in my coordinate system where origin is in the center of pixmap and maps it to the pixmap's coordinate system. Then calls colorPoint routine on those points to color the appropriate pixel.
colorPoint Simply colors the point it has accepted in the parameter.
visited and  pts are QSet and QHash respectively.



colorPoint is very expensive.  All the stuff in there, except for drawPoint, should be done only once, not for every pixel.

#pragma omp critical in a #pragma omp parallel for section make no sense, at all. The later is meant to parallelise the loop and the former is meant to serialize it. What the point to serialize a parallel loop? It just make it much slower by randomly scheduling it on multiple cores (with very expensive context-switch and cache-miss overheads)

Use QImage for painting. Test if that improves performance.

@MattTimmermans thank you very much, I made a new routine for plotting multiple points in the canvas, now it works faster. Earlier I was fetching canvas for plotting one point reassining it.
